# Concurrency: What's a channel?

Tags: concurrency, pascal-fc

I'm studying pascal-fc for a concurrency test.

I'm familiar with Java's threads and its monitors.

I don't understand the role of channels, please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *channel* is a kind of object that links a *receiver* and a *sender*.

In **Pascal-FC** they are strongly typed: you have to declare what kind of object they allow to be sent and received. You can really imagine them as channels in the sense that a process opens a channel of `integers` with another process: it will be able to send and receive `integers` from that channel, and the other process too.

It's a communication device on which you can do mainly 2 operations:

- `send`, defined as `channel_var ! expression`
- `receive`, defined as `channel_var ? variable`